# Type conversion using TypeScript interface

Tags: typescript, graphql

This is kind of a weird question but I'm working on a massive form containing approximately ~100 input fields. We're passing all this data to a GraphQL endpoint. We're using TypeScript and I've defined Interfaces based on the schema.

I want to know if I can use TypeScript's interface types, to be specific the type boolean, to convert certain property values automatically to `true` or `false` since they arrive from the form as strings `"1"` or `"0"`, or `"true"` (checkboxes)? I could then build something of a filter/converter to convert certain input types for GraphQL requests automatically when I can detect it from the Interface. There was a suggestion to do something like this, here on StackOverflow:

```
interface I1 {
    x: boolean; 
}

let myVar: I1['x'];
```

But you cannot use `myVar` as it is defined. I would like to get `typeof I1.x` so I can get back 'boolean' and then do a conversion for some fields such as `!!(obj.x)` etc.

So can I go about this or do I really have to generate a massive object tree converting or defining specific keys, again (duplication), to be boolean? Or do we have to think about using boolean values with GraphQ?

Comment: One solution for this would be to actually pass "true" from a checkbox and just check it using type safe comparison then convert those automatically to boolean. False values would not be passed but ignored.

Comment: This cannot be possible using interfaces, because interfaces are erased entirely when Typescript is compiled to Javascript; they have no effect at runtime.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a way to do the conversion using only interfaces, but could you not implement the interface in a class to achieve a similar outcome? Something along the lines of:

```
interface IOne {
    x : boolean
}

class One implements IOne {
    constructor(b_val?: boolean, b_str?: string) {
        if (b_val): this.x = b_val
        if (b_str) {
            if (b_str == 'true')
                this.x = true
            else
                this.x = false
        }
    }
}
```

Then you process input with `new One(true, undefined)` or `new One(undefined, 'true')`, etc. to get the conversion done for different input types, and you can pass the resulting object directly to anything that can consume the `IOne` interface.